# javascript: Check for existance of several specific object properties (also in coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, properties, coffeescript

I need to check whether several specific properties exist in an object. And for that I have two questions:

1. How am I generally supposed to check for several existing properties in JavaScript?
2. Is there a shortcut in CoffeeScript to do this in an elegant way?

My javascript solution would be:

```
if(obj && obj.pOne && obj.pTwo && obj.pThree) doStuff();
```

In coffee script that would be no shorter:

```
if obj and obj.pOne and obj.pTwo and obj.pThree then doStuff()
```

Don't get mislead here, it's not going to work:

<strike>And then I ran into the `in` operator for if clauses (which I never used for such checks). Is this the right way to do what I want to achieve?
Or is that some sort of no-go, or is there a better/cleaner solution to that?</strike>

My code would then look like this:

```
if(obj && ('pOne' && 'pTwo' && 'pThree' in obj)) doStuff();
```

and coffeescript like this:

```
if obj and ('pOne' and 'pTwo' and 'pThree' of obj) then doStuff()
```

Comment: !!!DON'T COPY MY SECOND SUGGESTION TO USE THE `in` OPERATOR TOGETHER WITH `&&` CONCATENATION!!! I just found out the above solution with `in` doesn't do at all what I want to achieve! It only checks the last property since this is the result of the `&&` concatenation. I should have known it... seems I have to stick with the first solution, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is what you want. There's nothing wrong with this, as it is. Maybe consider writing your function differently if you think you need to check 4 things before calling a function.

```
if(obj && obj.pOne && obj.pTwo && obj.pThree) doStuff();
```

See this: [Why Defensive Programming is Rubbish](http://danielroop.com/blog/2009/10/15/why-defensive-programming-is-rubbish/)

**PS**. Your last examples are no good and don't evaluate the way you think they do

---

Consider rewriting the function to make it nicer to use

```
var doStuff = function(obj) {
  obj        = obj        || {};
  obj.pOne   = obj.pOne   || "pOneDefault";
  obj.pTwo   = obj.pTwo   || "pTwoDefault";
  obj.pThree = obj.pThree || "pThreeDefault";

  console.log(obj);
};

doStuff();
// {pOne: "pOneDefault", pTwo: "pTwoDefault", pThree: "pThreeDefault"}

doStuff({pOne: "foo"});
// {pOne: "foo", pTwo: "pTwoDefault", pThree: "pThreeDefault"}

doStuff({pTwo: "bar"});
// {pTwo: "bar", pOne: "pOneDefault", pThree: "pThreeDefault"}

doStuff({pTwo: "hello", pThree: "world"});
// {pTwo: "hello", pThree: "world", pOne: "pOneDefault"}
```

Comment: I agree on the defensive programming article, but it doesn't apply here since the object I receive is a parsed config file from the user. And I do the checks to notify him whether he has all the necessary properties defined or else stop the execution of the program.

Answer (score 2):

`pOne in obj` is not the same as `obj.pOne`. For example, for `obj = { a: 0 }`, `a in obj` is `true`, but `obj.a` is falsy.

`('pOne' && 'pTwo' && 'pThree' in obj)` does not mean what you think; it evaluates as `('pOne' && 'pTwo' && ('pThree' in obj))`, which is same as `true && true && ('pThree' in obj)`.

Although verbose, if you want to catch the difference between falsy values and nonexistent keys, this is still the best way:

```
if (obj && 'pOne' in obj && 'pTwo' in obj && 'pThree' in obj)
```

If you think that the properties might be inherited, then using `obj.hasOwnProperty('pOne')` instead of `'pOne' in obj` is better still.